# jquery hide all and show child

Tags: jquery

I have links when you click it shows the specific `div` and the rest hides. It all is working fine but it's coded all manually one by one. See http://jsfiddle.net/M9kAX/

Is there a better way to code it with a simple script that applies for all `divs`?

Thanks,

```
<div class="kosa">
<div id="video0"><h5>Introduction</h5>  
Intro
</div>          
<div id="video1"><h5>Install </h5>  
Install
</div>
<div id="video2"><h5>Authorize with Adobe ID</h5>
Authorize
</div>
<div id="video3"><h5>Add a Library</h5>
Add Lib
</div>
<div id="video4"><h5>Borrow titles</h5>
Borrow
</div>
<div id="video5"><h5>Download</h5>
Download
</div>
<div id="video6"><h5>Read eBooks</h5>
Read
</div>
<div id="video7"><h5>Delete, Return, & Share</h5>
Del
</div>
<div id="video8"><h5>One</h5>
One
</div>
</div>
       <div class="related">    
            <h5>Related Videos</h5>
            <span id="link0"><i class="icon-video"></i> Introduction</span>
            <span id="link1"><i class="icon-video"></i> Install</span>
            <span id="link2"><i class="icon-video"></i> Authorize with Adobe ID</span>
            <span id="link3"><i class="icon-video"></i> Add a Library</span>
            <span id="link4"><i class="icon-video"></i> Borrow titles</span>
            <span id="link5"><i class="icon-video"></i> Download</span>
            <span id="link6"><i class="icon-video"></i> Read eBooks</span>
            <span id="link7"><i class="icon-video"></i> Delete, Return, & Share</span>
            <span id="link8"><i class="icon-video"></i> One</span>
         </div>

$(function() {      
        $('#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide();   
        $('#link0').click(function () {$('#video0').show();$('#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link1').click(function () {$('#video1').show();$('#video0,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link2').click(function () {$('#video2').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link3').click(function () {$('#video3').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link4').click(function () {$('#video4').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video3,#video5,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link5').click(function () {$('#video5').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video6,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link6').click(function () {$('#video6').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video7,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link7').click(function () {$('#video7').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video8').hide(); });
        $('#link8').click(function () {$('#video8').show();$('#video0,#video1,#video2,#video3,#video4,#video5,#video6,#video7').hide(); });
        });
```

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: I asked a similar question earlier today, check that out the answer I got was great...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427353/condense-repetitive-jquery-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M9kAX/12/)***

```
$('[id^=video]').hide();
$('#video0').show(); //show only 1st one

//events on ids which begin with link i.e., link0, link1...
$('[id^=link]').click(function() {
    var newId = this.id.replace("link","video"); //make a new ID
    $('[id^=video]').hide();//hide all divs first
    $('#' + newId).show();//show specific div
});
```

Comment: Was going to post an answer myself but this is so close I'll just explain why mine would be different.  Use `this.id.replace("link", "video")` so that is works if the page has more than 10 videos ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute:

```
<span id="link0" data-video="video0"><i class="icon-video"></i> Introduction</span>
```

Add the video ID to each span with `data-video`, then you can use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function to retrieve the value and show the div you want:

```
$(function() {      
    $('.kosa div').hide();
    // $('.kosa div:first').show(); // uncomment this line to show the frst div by default
    $('.related span').click(function() {
       $('.kosa div').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).data('video')).show();
    });
});
```

This approach is more flexible than using the `.eq` function, which would force you to move around your divs and make sure they were in the right order each time you made an edit. This also allows you to link to the same div with multiple spans if you need to.

http://jsfiddle.net/M9kAX/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use css `classNames`([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/M9kAX/9/)):

```
$(function () {
    var $videos = $('.video');

    var showVideo = function (index) {
        $videos.hide().eq(index).show();
    };

    showVideo(0);

    $('.link').click(function () {
        var linkIndex = $(this).index() - 1;
        showVideo(linkIndex)
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[try something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/BmfT6/)

```
$(function() {      
    $("span").click(function(){
        $("div.kosa").find("div#video").html($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery (".kosa")    .find ("div:first-child")
                    .css ("display", "block");

jQuery (".related")    .find ("span")
.click (function () {
       $idNo = jQuery (this).attr ('id').substring(4); 
    jQuery (".kosa")    .find ("div")
                        .css ("display", "none");

    jQuery (".kosa")    .find ("#video" + $idNo)
                        .css ("display", "block");
});
```

Css change:

```
.kosa div{
    padding:40px;
    background:#ccc; 
    display: none; // Included
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M9kAX/11/